# Is there is any way to create popup form on button click in SharePoint Add-In

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, javascript, sharepoint-addin, client-object-model

I am trying to create popup form on button click when i click on "create document" button then popup will be open and on that popup form i need one text box and button.

please let me know how can i implement this in SharePoint Add-In .

[image]

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample which I tested early.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/CustomJS.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var hostweburl;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            hostweburl =
                decodeURIComponent(
                    getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl")
            );
            var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";
            //Do not change the order, scripts should load by order. 

            $.getScript(scriptbase + "init.js").done(function () {
                $.getScript(scriptbase + "sp.runtime.js").done(function () {
                    $.getScript(scriptbase + "sp.js").done(function () {
                        $.getScript(scriptbase + "ScriptResx.ashx?name=sp.res&culture=en-us").done(function () {
                            $.getScript(scriptbase + "sp.init.js").done(function () {
                                $.getScript(scriptbase + "sp.ui.dialog.js").done(function () {
                                    $.getStylesheet(scriptbase + '/1033/styles/corev15.css').done(function () {
                                        sharePointReady(hostweburl);
                                    })
                                })
                            })
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        });
        (function ($) {
            $.getStylesheet = function (href) {
                var $d = $.Deferred();
                var $link = $('<link/>', {
                    rel: 'stylesheet',
                    type: 'text/css',
                    href: href
                }).appendTo('head');
                $d.resolve($link);
                return $d.promise();
            };
        })(jQuery);
        function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
            var params =
                document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
            var strParams = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
                var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
                if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
                    return singleParam[1];
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CustomJS.js

```
function sharePointReady(hostweburl) {            
    var _html = document.createElement('h1');
    _html.innerHTML = 'SharePoint Ready';
    var _options = { html: _html };
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(_options);
    //fix for close button
    $('.ms-dlgCloseBtnImg').attr('src', hostweburl + '/_layouts/15/images/fgimg.png?rev=44');

}
```